# How to distribute kubernetes config

Tags: kubernetes

How can I distribute the kube config file on worker nodes?

Only my master node has it (file under `~/.kube/config`), and I'm not sure what's the proper way to programmatically copy the file over to the worker nodes, so that I can use `kubectl` on all nodes.

Comment: `kubeconfig` file is basically the master key to your Kubernetes cluster. Be careful on how many copies you want it to spread around ...

Comment: Good point, thanks @Lukman. What should I do if for example I want to do some maintenance on worker nodes, and I have to run things like `kubectl cordon`, `kubectl drain`, etc. on those nodes?

Comment: You only need to cordon & drain worker nodes but not master node(s), right? Then you only need to run `kubectl` on master node which will direct the operations that you want to the specific worker nodes. You do not need to run `kubectl` on the worker node that you want to cordon/drain. You can even run `kubectl` from your local machine on the other side of the globe as long as it can access the cluster API.

Comment: Ah you mean I can, from the master, do things like `kubectl cordon <worker-node>`. Right? (Not only I can, but I should)

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the scp command in order to copy a file from one machine to another one.

run the following command from your master node for each worker node :

```
[user@k8s-master]$ scp ~/.kube/config username@k8s-worker1:~/.kube/config
```

Comment: Yeah I used `scp` in the end. I was wondering if there was some specific kubernetes command that allowed to do that, as part of the setup.

Is it common to want to be able to run `kubectl` on worker nodes? I'm not sure if I should avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended that you have ~/.kube/config on the worker nodes. If a worker node is compromised due to a vulnerable pod, it could compromise the cluster using this config.

Thats why it is recommended to use a bastion host and use kube context.

However, for non-prod environments,

you can do something like this

```
kubectl get no --no-headers | egrep -v "master|controlplane" |  awk '{print $1}' | while read line; do 
    scp -pr ~/.kube/ ${line}:~/.kube; 
done
```

scp -pr will create the .kube  directory if it doesn't exist on the  worker nodes